# Is it a good practice to use AWS KMS Key as Customer Provided Key (SSE-C) for S3 encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-kms

For using AWS S3 SSE-C, we need to provide our own encryption key. But after reading too much, I decided to create AWS KMS Customer Managed Key and create Data Encryption Key for a folder. And save the Encryption Wrapped DEK in Database for further encryption / decryption. So I would like to know if this is a good approach.

For some reasons, I need to separate the keys for each folder.